# How can I use mogrify to target a specific pixel value of the largest dimension so if vertical set height to 'x' or if horizontal, set width to 'x'

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, mogrify

So I've successfully used `$ mogrify -resize 3000` to accomplish setting dimension on batches of images. What this yields me is exactly that- a group of images that have a 3000px width. The issue lies in vertical images that now have a vertical value larger than I would like.

My question is: Is there a solution that assesses the largest value (height or width) and then assigns the resize to that dimension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give both dimensions, it will resize until one dimension matches at least. So just use `-resize 3000x3000`. If you don't want to resize downwards you can add the suffix `<` so that only smaller images will grow to 3000, and larger images will be untouched (`-resize '3000x3000<'`). Similarly, suffix `>` to not resize upwards.

Comment: If I do that won't it force both to 3000? Im aiming to have one target dimension and the other to float within its current aspect ratio.

Comment: @visyoual [No: “Resize will fit the image into the requested size. It does NOT fill, the requested box size.”](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize). (Unless you pass the suffix `!` to ignore the aspect ratio.)